# download control using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

We have a problem in our download server and wanna solve it via htaccess.
our download server is directory of many files with `zip|rar|mp3|wmv|flv` extension that users should not direct access to them.

We want this scenario: when every user request such files; we redirect him to a page (e.g. `download.php`) and and update our statistics about that file then redirect him to url(so just this page can download a file.)

I searched about it and found a syntax but it seems somthings wrong! can u help me:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
# CLOSE HOTLINKS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?myserver.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp3|wmv|flv|exe|rar|zip|jpg)$ http://mydownloadserver.com/download.php?url=$1 [L]
```

---

with thanks to Mihai so we can solve our problem with this htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?anotherAllowedDomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?MyDownloadServer.com/download.php.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.*.(mp3|wmv|flv|exe|rar|zip|jpg)$ http://MyDownloadServer.com/download.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

and finally process all requests in "download.php"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot any file name:

```
RewriteRule \.*.(mp3|mp4)$ http://mydownloadserver.com/download.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` will return the uri requested and you can process from there like ([readfile()](http://uk.php.net/readfile))

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
deny from all
```

in your .htaccess. You can use your php page to do certain operations and let user download the file.

PS. If i were you, i dont want such users to redirect to a download page if they try to access files directly. Its kinda illegal in my scenario if they do what they are not suppose to do. So i will show them forbidden page if they try to acccess the files directly.

Comment: i know that i can use deny and redirect all 403 to download.php page but then we can't understand which page users come from!!